# GridView Automatically text upper case in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hello I have created below mentioned GridView

```
<asp:GridView ID="dgvReportOrderId" runat="server"
                    CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" GridLines="None"
                    AutoGenerateColumns="False" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="10" OnPageIndexChanging="dgvReportOrderId_PageIndexChanging">
                    <Columns>
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="OrderId" HeaderText="OrderId" />
                        <asp:BoundField DataField="Count" HeaderText="Count" />
                    </Columns>
                    <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Right" CssClass="GridPager" />
                    <EmptyDataTemplate>
                        No Data Found 
                    </EmptyDataTemplate>
                </asp:GridView>
```

and I have binded it with data, in data there is a lower case but when I see in browser it will be uppercase even I have checked with developer tool then I found the result as

[image]

can anyone please let me know where I have to check for this prob

Comment: What is in the  'cursor-pointer" class?

Comment: it's just cursor style .cursor-pointer{cursor:pointer} I have already tried to remove that class but not resolved

Comment: Alll i want to say is there any css modified text style properties?

Comment: no I have checked it my whole project there is no style apply for capitalize

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `td` or one of its ancestors has the `text-transform: uppercase;` CSS property applied to it.

Comment: I have checked it there is no such class apply in my whole project

Comment: I have find text-transform: capitalize; in only bootstrap.css

Comment: got it I have put the text-transform: capitalize; in body class

Comment: My bad on that, it's `uppercase`, not `capitalize`.